# polymer how to get children of the same type

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I am still experimenting how far I can go with building a widget in Polymer and I am stuck in one place. I want to create an element with children that are also polymer elements. Something like:

```
<my-view name="Hello">
    <my-child-view attribute="test">Test</my-child-view>
    <my-child-view attribute="test1">Test2</my-child-view>
    <my-child-view attribute="test2">Test3</my-child-view>
    <my-child-view attribute="test3"></my-child-view>
    <my-other-child-view var="test5"></my-other-child-view>
</my-view>
```

I want to get children that are the tag name "my-child-view". Using `this.children` takes all the children. Is there a native polymer functionality like `this.getChildrenWithQuery('my-child-view')`? Or should I just loop through children and check the ones with tag name myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.querySelectorAll('my-child-view')
```

Native JS DOM! Yes, [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll) works on elements as well as the document.

Comment: hmm. interesting thing happened. I cannot access the elements attributes when using querySelectorAll...

Comment: @Gasim It returns a `NodeList` of elements. Are you sure you're getting a single element out of it?

Comment: Or use `Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodeList, function() {...})` to operate on each of the returned nodes (otherwise you'd be using plain ol' querySelector, right?)

Comment: The problem happened because I couldn't use the syntax "for(i in nodes)" because It would return bunch of other node list values too